# Why spring data dynamodb are returning a list with null element instead a empty list?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, amazon-dynamodb

When I invoke a repository method that makes a key search in dynamo:

[image]

```json
"{"TableName":"music","Key":{"artist":{"S":"Henrique"},"title":{"S":"Quinta_de_sol1"}},"ConsistentRead":false}"
```

this is aws output:

```json
"{}"
```

And when i invoke another methos that makes a find using sortKey start with:

[image]

this is sent to aws:

```json
"{"TableName":"music","ConsistentRead":true,"KeyConditions":{"artist":{"AttributeValueList":[{"S":"Djavan"}],"ComparisonOperator":"EQ"},"title":{"AttributeValueList":[{"S":"Tempo"}],"ComparisonOperator":"BEGINS_WITH"}},"ScanIndexForward":true}"
```

and this is the return:

```json
"{"Count":0,"Items":[],"ScannedCount":0}"
```

### Steps to Reproduce the Problem

Using a entity named Music

```java
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "music")
data class Music(

        @get:DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "artist")
        var artist: String? = null,

        @get:DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "title")
        var title: String? = null,

        var genre: String? = null
) {

    @Id
    private var id: MusicId? = null
        get() = MusicId(artist, title)
}

@DynamoDBDocument
data class MusicId(

        @field:DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "artist")
        var artist: String? = null,

        @field:DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "title")
        var title: String? = null
) : Serializable
```

And a repository

```java
interface MusicRepository : CrudRepository<Music, MusicId> {

    fun findByArtistAndTitle(artist: String, title: String): List<Music>

    fun findByArtistAndTitleStartingWith(artista: String, sortKey: String): List<Music>
}
```

And when i invoke:

```java
@PostConstruct
    fun init() {
        println(musicRepository.findByArtistAndTitleStartingWith("Djavan", "Eu te devoro").joinToString())
    }
```

### Specifications

- Lib: https://github.com/boostchicken/spring-data-dynamodb
- Spring Data DynamoDB Version:  5.2.5
- Spring Data Version: Doesn't used
- Spring Boot Starter Web Version: 2.3.4.RELEASE
- AWS SDK Version: 1.11.573
- Java Version: 11
- Platform Details: Windows

**Someone know if is there a clean way to guarantee that the dynamo repo will never return a list that only accepts non null elements, with null elements?**

Answer (score 2):

To write a Spring application that invokes Amazon DynamoDB, consider using the official Amazon DynamoDB Java V2 API and the enhanced client within a Spring project.

[Map items in DynamoDB tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb-enhanced.html)

If you are not familiar with the AWS SDK for Java V2, please refer to this [Quick Start](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html).